# Check if Compiler supports optional C feature in the source

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c11

I have a simple program (a VERY simplistic malloc/free implementation, originally written for a university assignment), which has to check the "validity" of the pointers in the free, for which I need to dereference it. To avoid Segfaults when a user supplies a bs pointer, I want to check if the memory is currently mapped into my Addressspace.

I wanted to do this with something like

```
char* pointer_to_memory;

free(void *ptr) {
    if((uintptr_t)ptr < (uintptr_t)pointer_to_memory) {
        abort();
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, that c11 has uintptr_t as an optional feature, meaning not all compiler support that.
I don't really NEED the code, so I would be willing to just leave it out when compiling with a compiler that doesn't support uintptr_t with some kind of preprocessor magic.
I know, that pointer to integer casts are not always working like one would expect them to (ARM seems to have some additional info in the pointers for Example) but it seemed better defined than (direct) pointer comparisons.
I also can't just ignore the SIGSEGV, since I want to stay true to the university assignment and we were not allowed to use Signal Handlers (and I suspect a SIGSEGV hander is not something you should overwrite as a free)

Comment: If `UINTPTR_MAX` (a macro) is defined, then `uintptr_t` is available. However in general you cannot test if a pointer is valid.

Comment: What about NULL?

Comment: @Lundin NULL is treated separately, before it even reaches this check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would be willing to just leave it out when compiling with a compiler that doesn't support uintptr_t with some kind of preprocessor magic.

As pointed out by 
[n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m), you can use `UINTPTR_MAX`:

```
char* pointer_to_memory;

free(void *ptr)
{
    #if defined(UINTPTR_MAX)
    if((uintptr_t)ptr < (uintptr_t)pointer_to_memory) {
        abort();
    }
    #endif
    // ...
}
```

> To avoid Segfaults when a user supplies a bs pointer, I want to check if the memory is currently mapped into my Addressspace.

You cannot force the user to write "correct" programs in C. If C, by design, allows somebody to shoot themselves in the foot, you will never be able stop them programatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can detect optional features.

One of them is checking a preprocessor macro. **If** (and that's is a strong if) your compiler is following a standard, you can expect some preprocessor macro to be set depending on the faeture. For `uintptr_t` that would be `UINTPTR_MAX` from `stdint.h` file.

Some compilers do not follow a standard. For example, a compiler may give you `uintptr_t` without `UINTPTR_MAX`.

The second thing is to compile an example program that uses the feature, remember if the compilation suceeded, and then set a custom preprocessor macro or different action when compiling your code. This is the way build systems work. Autotools has `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`, CMake has `try_compile` to check a compilation of a program. Then depending on the result of compilation, set a preprocessor macro in your program, or in case of autotools, you would generate a different `config.h` file.

```
// CMakeLists.txt
string(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "stdint.h" "limits.h")
include(CheckTypeSize)
check_type_size("uintptr_t" UINTPTR)
if(HAVE_UINTPTR)
   target_compile_definition(yourlib  PREFIX_HAS_UINTPTR)
endif()


// your C code
   #ifdef PREFIX_HAS_UINTPTR
   // use uintptr_t
   #endif
```